# Merge items in list of floats

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

My seraching creativity didn't provide useable results so far, so I have to ask this question...

I have a group of related (figure-like) item types (music examples) which I include in different ways:

1. a floating environment defined with `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment`
2. a non-floating environment (allowing page breaks)
3. a full-page command using \includepdf internally.

I managed to let the environments share a counter (the one from 1.), but I don't know how I can include the non-floating versions in a \listofmusicexamples.

Probably I would find a way to directly write a line into the auxiliary file from 2. and 3., but isn't there a less hacky way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for any hint or suggestion

---

Unfortunately I have to revoke my comment somewhat. Using `\captionsetup` only works smoothly in my non-floating environment (2.) but not in the command 3.

Using the command environment gives a warning `\captionsetup{type=...} (caption) outside box or environment`.
While I could live with that warning I just realized that this command affects paragraph formatting afterwards.
After the first appearance of my command all paragraphs are not indented anymore (they now are like the captions(?)).

If I enclose everything with a \begingroup \endgroup I get lots of errors, but the document compiles and the paragraph formatting is correct again.
So my assumption seems right that somehow the caption's formatting was kept active.
I tried some kinds of other approaches but none seems to work.

So I had to reimplement 3. by manually incrementing the counter with `\refstepcounter` and adding an entry to the list with `\addcontentsline`

Comment: If you put `\captionsetup{type=...}` within your non-floating environment you could use `\caption` for captioning and listing the environment. Otherwise you could use `\captionlistentry` for the list entry. (See caption package doc for details)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I made a workaround to use 'fake' captions, but having real \captions would make it more consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put `\captionsetup{type=...}` within your non-floating environment you could use `\caption` for captioning and listing the environment. Otherwise you could use `\captionlistentry` for the list entry. (See `caption` package doc for details)

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{test}

\begin{document}

\listoftests

\begin{test}
  ...
  \caption{A}
\end{test}

\begin{center}
  \captionsetup{type=test}
  ...
  \caption{B}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  \captionsetup{type=test}
  ...
  \captionlistentry{C}
  ...
\end{center}

\captionlistentry[test]{D}

\end{document}
```